# Android Unit test - mock inner class method

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking

Class A has a method which create new instance of class B and call to Android API functionality.

```
Class A{

    public void foo(){
        B b = new B();

        //some code

        b.callAndroidAPI()

        //some code

    }
}
```

How can i do unit test for class b foo() method. Is there any way to override/mock the callAndroidAPI() before calling to foo()?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the "new" creation to another method and then override that method with a mock:

```
Class A {

B getB() {
  return new B();
}

public void foo(){
    B b = getB();

    //some code

    b.callAndroidAPI()

    //some code

}
```

}

Then in your tests, you can override the **getB** call.

```
@Test
public void testBFoo() {
    A a = new A() {
        B getB() {
          return bMocked;
        }
    }

    // verify interactions
}
```

Also, I wrote about this recently: http://www.adavis.info/2015/11/testing-tricks-1-dealing-with-new.html